# Solving electrical network in Python

Tags: python, physics

I have a complicated electrical network. I would like to calculate the voltage drop across across the network, i.e. nodes 2-15, given `V1=10 V` and `V16=0 V`. The values of the resistances are known.

Is there a Python package which can calculate this? I can the write equation for each node using Ohm's and Kirchoff's laws, but then manually solving 14 linear equations simultaneously is tedious.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use qucs (opensource) for Windows and Linux to solve complicated electrical networks in ac source or dc source and transient modes. You can download it on most Linux distros or compile it yourself. You set up the circuit schematic graphically, provide the power source and ground connections, set up what voltages or currents, or powers you wish to display and start it.  You can get plots or tabular output.  It is not Python but a standalone app.

There is an offshoot qucs-s that is used for very complicated networks with solid state components.  Again, this is not Python.

Also LTspice will solve virtually any electrical circuit. I am not proficient with this at all but I am confident it could solve the circuit you displayed.  Again, not Python but a standalone app.

Comment: Including links would be helpful.

Comment: @eric s -- Are you too lazy to do a duck-duck-go search on qucs, qucs-s, and ltspice? Give that a whirl

Comment: I am not lazy. I'm trying to help you improve your answer. Providing a link is a kind convenience to users. You put in a little effort to save others many little efforts. Insulting people is an excellent way of obtaining downvotes.